# Memory value changes during runtime without a write operation

Tags: assembly, nasm

I am writing the following program in the SASM IDE using NASM. I have a variable m that is not being changed only read (for now). Somehow after the div operation, it looks like m changes from 6 to 983046.

Here is the full .asm code:

```
; TO COMPILE:
; nasm -f elf -g -F stabs lab.asm -l lab.lst
; gcc -m32 lab.o -o lab

global main
extern printf

SECTION .data

m DW 6 ; Number being check for perf median
t DW 0 ; Sum of preceeding numbers
n DW 0 ; Sum of suceeding numbers
d DW 0.5

SECTION .text

main:
; Safe registers are EBX, EBP, ESI, EDI, and ESP.
; Formula to find 1-6 (including the number 6

push message
call printf
add esp, 4

mov ebx, [m]
; Test print variable
push ebx
push dataM ; Needed to format the value as "%d"
call printf
add esp, 8

; Calculate T
mov ebx, [m]
mov edi, [m]
dec ebx

imul ebx, edi
mov [t], ebx

mov ax, [t]
mov bl, 2
div bl


mov [t], ax ; Done Calculating t
mov ebx, [t] 

push ebx
push dataM2 ; Needed to format the value as "%d"
call printf
add esp, 8

; This Doesn't work?
mov ebx, [m] ; Value of m has seemingly changed??

push ebx
push dataM2 ; Needed to format the value as "%d"
call printf
add esp, 8



ret


message:
db "Lab_2 Start:", 10,0

dataM:
db "Testing: %d...", 10, 0

dataM2:
db "DEBUG: %d", 10, 0
```

Output:

```
Lab_2 Start:
Testing: 6...
DEBUG: 15
DEBUG: 983046
```

(Expected) Output:

```
Lab_2 Start:
Testing: 6...
DEBUG: 15
DEBUG: 6
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you've declared all your variables as *words* (16 bits), but you keep reading and writing 32-bit registers from/to them.

You need to either:

1. Change your variable declarations from `DW` to `DD` (doubleword).
2. Use 16-bit registers like `ax`, `bx`, `cx`, etc when accessing your variables.

You can also extend a 16-bit value to 32 bits, e.g. `movsx ebx,word [m]`. But that's only relevant when reading from memory.

Comment: I'd consider it relevant when moving from a smaller register to a larger one as well.